# IS this possible to modify multiple variable from same file using a .batch file without effecting other things like space, special char?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file rev.ini having multiple variable to update:

```
s1=10
s2=20
s3=30
```

Here I am using separate loop for finding string in a file. there are 3 times loop are running for same file. Is it possible to find these three string in same loop?

```
@Echo Off
cd /d D:\xyz
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set s1=10
set s2=11
set s3=12
set "file=rev.ini"
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "s1= "  rev.ini') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set sequence=%s1%
)
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!

    echo(!line!>>!file!
)


for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "s2= " rev.ini') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set sequence=%s2%
)
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!

    echo(!line!>>!file!
)

for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i in ('findstr "s3= "  rev.ini') do (
    set "versionVar=%%~i"
    set "versionVal=%%~j"
    set sequence=%s3%
)
for /f "tokens=1,*delims=]" %%i in ('type "%file%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break^>%file%') do (
    set "line=%%j"
    if "!line!" == "!versionVar!=!versionVal!" set line=!versionVar!=!sequence!

    echo(!line!>>!file!
)


Goto :EOF
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I agree with the above, it most certainly is. However, this site isn't here to rewrite your code for you. The main thing you should investigate, in making the improvements you're seeking, is the `findstr.exe` utility options, because it can accept multiple strings/patterns, and read from multiple files in one command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74276740.txt"
SET "outfile=outfile.txt"

set "s1=10"
set "s2=11"
set "s3=12"


REM (
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "#keep=Y"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%u IN ('set') DO (IF /i "%%b"=="%%u" SET "#keep="&ECHO %%b=%%v)
 IF DEFINED #keep IF "%%c"=="" (ECHO %%b) ELSE (ECHO %%b=%%c)
)
REM )>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Simply read each line. If the line contains `=` and the part before the `=` contains any variablename in the environment (I made it case-insensitive with `/i`) then generate a line using the matching value. If `#keep` remains set after the `for..%%u` has been executed, then there is no match, so either reproduce the original `x=y` or the original line, if it had no `=`.

The output file can be generated by removing the `rem` before the `(` and `)`.

The output file must be different from the input file, and should be moved over the input file when the batch finishes (not shown)

--- After comment ---

So, if you follow the instructions provided in the last two paragraphs, you get

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74276740.txt"
SET "outfile=outfile.txt"

set "s1=10"
set "s2=11"
set "s3=12"


(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims==" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "#keep=Y"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%u IN ('set') DO (IF /i "%%b"=="%%u" SET "#keep="&ECHO %%b=%%v)
 IF DEFINED #keep IF "%%c"=="" (ECHO %%b) ELSE (ECHO %%b=%%c)
)
)>"%outfile%"

move "%outfile%" "%filename1%"

GOTO :EOF
```

== revision of processing section in light of new requirement to retain empty lines ==

```
REM (

FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=:=" %%g IN ('findstr /n ^^^^ "%filename1%"') DO IF "%%h"=="" (ECHO.) ELSE (
 SET "#keep=Y"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%u IN ('set') DO (IF /i "%%h"=="%%u" SET "#keep="&ECHO %%h=%%v)
 IF DEFINED #keep IF "%%i"=="" (ECHO %%h) ELSE (ECHO %%h=%%i)
)
REM )>"%outfile%"
```

Once again, the `rem` keywords need to be removed to output to the nominated file.

The changes simply feed the file through a `findstr` command which produces a listing of the file with a prefix of `linenumber:`. The extra `:` in the `delims` causes the line number to be parsed to `%%g`. I've changed the metavariable letters because three are required for the processing, and I prefer to not use letters that are also modifiers.

If `findstr` produces only a line number then it was a blank line, so `%%h` will be empty and we simply produce an empty line, otherwise, processing as before.

Comment: ,Sorry for asking again but I am new for this. When I am running this batch file it removes the spaces. like s1=10 s2=40              s3=50. I create a space between s2 and s3 it removes the spaces between s2 and s3

Comment: You would need post a sample of your file by `edit`ing it into your question. Do you mean you have lines like `s1=1 s2=2 s3=3` (where `s2` and `s3` should have disappeared, or do you mean you want to preserve blank lines in the file?

Comment: ,I mean for ex: s2=1 at lineno 3 and s3=2 at line no 5 .when I execute the script  s3=2 move to lineno 4. it remove the space between s2 and s3

Comment: So - line 4 is empty, and you want to preserve empty lines?

Comment: ,yes, I want preserve empty line.
I don't want change  anything in my file except that  I want